# How do I remove duplicate lines and ignore some of the text?

Tags: java

There is a list containing lines of the following form:

**1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z**

How do I remove duplicate lines but still ignore the date? that is, ignore the date at the end of the line:

**::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z**

Only the first part of the string before the date is important:

**1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg**

Comment: What about using split (and trim to remove the last blank space, if you want) to get the relevant part of the String?

Comment: Put all lines in a `Map` using the first part of the string as the key. Or use a `List` and only add new lines when the List does not already contain a line with the first part.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RubioRic  This is not a solution.

Comment: No, this is a comment

Comment: @ronpi I do not know how to do this due to lack of knowledge. Therefore, I ask for help.

Comment: @MichaelJosephJackson do you already know how to a) read the lines of a file, b) split each line to get the 2 different parts and c) check for duplicates based on the first part? This question covers many aspects...

Comment: @MichaelJosephJackson then you should try something first, not just drop your assignments on SO.

Comment: `line = line.replaceAll("(.+\\.jpg).*", "$1");` should do it

Comment: @MichaelJosephJackson You can split with the ::: and then you can keep the first part of strings in a set. Then there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: @MichaelJosephJackson If there is a duplicate, but there are two different dates, which date do you want to keep (i.e. the one that appeared first? the one that appeared last? the earliest date? the latest date?). The answer to this question might guide you towards an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z",
            "1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d4.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z",
            "1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:00Z"};

    HashMap<String, String> outMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> keys = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String line:input) {
        String key = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":::"));
        String oldVal = outMap.putIfAbsent(key, line);
        if(oldVal==null) {
            keys.add(key);
        }
    }
    List<String> collect = keys.stream().map(key -> outMap.get(key)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    collect.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

For each line, the part before the `:::` is treated as a key. The HashMap is used to remember if a line with that key was already encountered in the input list and the first occurrence is saved in the Map.

The `Map` has one problem though: the order of the things it contains is not preserved. To solve this, we remember the order of the keys using the `List<String> keys`.

This code prints:

```
1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z
1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d4.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If the  `:::` part is unique, and guaranteed to not occur in the first part you can do what @RubioRic has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268577/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-lines-and-ignore-some-of-the-text#comment122430209_69268577).

Split on the  `:::`, and then take the first part only. Now to check if two strings are matched, just pass them through this process of splitting, and compare their first part. If you have a collection of those string then iterate on the collection and store in a `HashSet` (or any other available mutable set) the first part of the past strings. Then for the following strings, check if their first part already exist in the set, if yes, filter them, otherwise keep them and add their first part to the set.

Comment: The HashMap or HashSet does not keep the original order of the lines in the file though.

Comment: First the set is used for filtering only using a `contains` functionality, and only stores the first part of the strings, and not their original form.  Second, if the collection is a `List`, then iterating it and filtering strings that their first part was already seen, will trivially preserve the order of the oroginal list, minus the filtered elements. Regardless of that, I didn't see any order requirement

Comment: I agree and that is what I also used in my answer. I deducted the order requirement from the vague "remove duplicates from a list".

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can do it like that

```
List<String> newList = holder.stream().map(value -> value.split(":")[0].trim()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. Split each element with the char ':' and get the first part
2. Trim the value
3. Remove duplicates
4. Return the new list

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       List<String> holder = new ArrayList<>();
       holder.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
       holder.add("2/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
       holder.add("2/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
       holder.add("3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
       holder.add("3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
       List<String> newList = holder.stream().map(value -> value.split(":")[0].trim()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
       newList.forEach(System.out::println);
   }
   ```

The output is :

```
1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg
2/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg
3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg
```

**EDIT:** The correct code should be:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String> holder = new ArrayList<>();
        holder.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("1/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("2/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("2/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        holder.add("3/ce/a6/5a/1cea65ab9260df8d55fb29ce0df570d3.jpg ::: 2021-09-17T17:07:52Z");
        
        Set<String> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        holder.stream().filter(e -> !set.contains(e.split(":")[0].trim())).forEach(set::add);
        set.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: This removes any timestamp from the output. The requirement is to keep it, just ignoring following lines where the part before the ::: is identical.

Comment: You have deleted the date. I didn't say delete the date, I said ignore and not delete.

Comment: I apologize if I offended you somehow.

@f1sh What you did, it could have been done much easier.

But your example is still bad.

Comment: @f1sh You're right. My bad... I edited my post.